# Values of derivative for a piece wise function

Tags: calculus, functions

[image]

I am a beginner in calculus and I am not exactly sure how to find the derivative of the graph in the diagram. Can someone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what the symbol $f'(1)$ means, geometrically?

Comment: I am completely new at this so I am not exactly sure.

Comment: Well, have you ever seen the symbol $f'(1)$ before? Have you read a definition of it? Do you know the word "derivative"?

Comment: A derivative is basically the instantaneous rate of change (the change at one single point) of a function.

Comment: f′(1) is the derivative of the function with an input of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative at a point is the slope of the tangent at that point. With this in mind, it is clear that $f'(1) = 0$ and $f'(3) = -1/2$.

Comment: Ahh okay, so the input (i.e 1 and 3) basically means to find the the slope of the tangent **at that point**, right? Thanks for the answer. :D